# Git Ignore file not working in Visual Studio when right clicking and pressing check in

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I have a project in visual studio (a website project).

The solution file is at the root and a example of the project folder:

```
/.git/
/www/
/stuff/
solutionfile
```

When I go to changes it detects the correct files that have been changes (as I excluded the wrong files earlier).

But if I right click the solution or the project in VS2012, and press commit, it wants to commit everything that have changes, ignoring what have been setup in the ignore file.

I have a line like this in the `.gitignore`:

```
/www/App_Data/tempfolder
```